# Java: Returning an extended class given it's name

Tags: java, generics, casting, extends, unchecked-cast

In the following code I am returning a class that extends the type of Entity given the name of the class (it then corrects it so that `Class.forName` can find it properly).

How can I modify this so that I can still return a class that extends Entity **without using** `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

I tired a few variations using `T` and just `?` but couldn't come up with an answer.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Class<? extends Entity> getProjectile(String name) {
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ARROW"))
        name = "Arrow";
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ENDERPEARL"))
        name = "EnderPearl";
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("EXPERIENCEORB"))
        name = "ExperienceOrb";
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("FIREBALL"))
        name = "Fireball";
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("FIREWORK"))
        name = "Firework";
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("SMALLFIREBALL"))
        name = "SmallFireball";
    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("SNOWBALL"))
        name = "Snowball";
    else
        name = "Egg";

    try {
        return (Class<? extends Entity>) Class.forName("org.bukkit.entity." + name);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return Egg.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but to clean up that code make the capital strings into an enum and to get rid of the if's - put a static block in the beginning and initiate a static Map<MyEnum, Class<?> Check the equality in the equals-method on the enum and implement hashcode as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Class.forName(String)` is declared as returning a reference of type `Class<?>` which you then have to cast if you want it to conform to `Class<? extends Entity>` This cast is unsafe so the compiler warns you.

The alternative is to have the actual `Class` objects in the `if-else` block instead of the names.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the class at compile time you can just return, say `org.bukkit.entity.Egg.class` instead of calling `forName`. If you can't you're stuck with the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can't guess whether class extends `Entity` just by looking at possible values for `Class.forName(...)` call.

You can use a `Class aClass` variable instead of `String name` for storing answer to avoid warning:

```
public static Class<? extends Entity> getProjectile(String name) {
    Class<? extends Entity> ans;

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ARROW"))
            ans = Arrow.class;
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("ENDERPEARL"))
            ans = EnderPearl.class;
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("EXPERIENCEORB"))
            ans = ExperienceOrb.class;
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("FIREBALL"))
            ans = Fireball.class;
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("FIREWORK"))
            ans = Firework.class;
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("SMALLFIREBALL"))
            ans = SmallFireball.class;
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("SNOWBALL"))
            ans = Snowball.class;
        else
            ans = Egg.class;

        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question: `Class.forname` isn't very 'safe' code, so you'll get compile messages. I'd say stick with what you have, as it works.

A few remarks: rather than that massive if block to determine the entity child's name, use the following code instead.

```
name = name.toLowerCase();
name = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
```